# Calculating non-exempt interest for California income tax

Tags: united-states, income-tax, interest, california

This question is about how California taxes interest on municipal bonds that are exempt from federal income tax.

I live in California. In 2023 year I received tax-exempt interest from a variety of municipal bonds. The CA "Interest and Dividend Adjustment Worksheet" asks for the following:

- Line B: California state tax exempt interest from federal schedule B.
- Line C: Of the amount on Line B, enter the portion attributable to funds where at least 50% of the assets are **not** invested in US/California municipal obligations.

I filled in line B based on schedule B, where I calculated my total tax exempt interest minus my bond premium on those bonds. My questions about the next step are:

1. My 1099-INT breaks down my tax exempt interest into CA and non-CA funds and shows three values: "Tax-exempt interest", "accrued interest paid", and "bond premium - covered lot". Is the proper amount to report on line C the tax-exempt interest minus the bond premium?
2. Does it matter that I own bonds instead of "funds" invested in bonds? The instructions seem oddly specific about the interest being from funds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the fund invests more than half of its assets in bonds from outside California, then *all* the fund interest is taxable, including that from CA bonds. See the [instructions for the CA FTB form 540 Schedule CA](https://www.ftb.ca.gov/forms/2022/2022-540-ca-instructions.html):

> Certain mutual funds pay “exempt-interest dividends.” If the mutual fund has at least 50 percent of its assets invested in tax-exempt U.S. obligations and/or in California or its municipal obligations, that amount of dividend is exempt from California tax.

So yes, it does matter if the interest is paid by bonds directly vs by a fund. If your bond is CA-exempt - then all of the interest is CA exempt. Line C only refers to funds.

Comment: Thank you! I was confused because I couldn't tell where else I would enter taxable bond interest but I see there's a space for it on Line E, and it gets added together with Line C. Now this makes sense.